# Displaying rows with count 0 with mysql sort

Tags: mysql

i want to order by column `Tgl` and then order by column `Usia` and i want my null row to display row with 0 value instead of skip it, i want to record all my rows even if they null

Lets say:
I dont have row data on date ='2017-09-02' I want dispaly it as 0 value instead if skip it
code:

```
SELECT CONCAT(DAY(`date`),' ',MONTHNAME(`date`),' ',YEAR(`date`)) AS Tgl,t.Usia, t.jmlCust
FROM(
SELECT '<20' AS Usia ,COALESCE(COUNT(*),0) AS jmlCust, `date` FROM getpoint gp
LEFT JOIN customer cs ON gp.CardID = cs.CardID
WHERE (YEAR(NOW())-YEAR(cs.tanggallahir))<20
AND nominalbelanja <> 0
GROUP BY DAY(gp.date)
UNION
SELECT '20-35' AS Usia ,COALESCE(COUNT(*),0) AS jmlCust, `date` FROM getpoint gp
LEFT JOIN customer cs ON gp.CardID = cs.CardID
WHERE (YEAR(NOW())-YEAR(cs.tanggallahir)) BETWEEN 20 AND 35
AND nominalbelanja <> 0
GROUP BY DAY(gp.date)
UNION
SELECT '36-50' AS Usia ,COALESCE(COUNT(*),0) AS jmlCust, `date` FROM getpoint gp
LEFT JOIN customer cs ON gp.CardID = cs.CardID
WHERE (YEAR(NOW())-YEAR(cs.tanggallahir)) BETWEEN 36 AND 50
AND nominalbelanja <> 0
GROUP BY DAY(gp.date)
UNION 
SELECT 'TOTAL' AS Usia ,COALESCE(COUNT(*),0) AS jmlCust,`date` FROM getpoint gp
LEFT JOIN customer cs ON gp.CardID = cs.CardID
WHERE nominalbelanja <> 0
GROUP BY DAY(gp.date)
ORDER BY `date`
) t
```

Comment: **i want my 0 row to display row 0 instead of skip it, i want to record all my rows even if they null code** please explain this. Are you getting zero rows? is this you want to say?

Comment: No, I want get 0 value instead of null, because null on order by will skip it

Comment: you can use `ifnull(column_name, 0)`

Comment: i already try it but the result still same, i already tried both, ifnull and coalesce()

Comment: So the only thing i can see now is, different queries in union are not producing any row. try running each query individually.

Comment: yea i tried query individualy the result is same, it is possible to display data per day even no data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156456/discussion-between-danang-januarko-and-surya-singh).

Answer (score 0):

create one temp table as below,

```
create table test1( 
Usia varchar(10)); 
insert into test1 values ('<20'),('20-35'),('36-50'),('TOTAL');
```

now apply join with your result table.

```
SELECT CONCAT(DAY(`date`),' ',MONTHNAME(`date`),' ',YEAR(`date`)) AS Tgl,test1.Usia, ifnull(t.jmlCust,0) 
FROM( 
SELECT '<20' AS Usia ,COALESCE(COUNT(*),0) AS jmlCust, `date` FROM getpoint gp 
LEFT JOIN customer cs ON gp.CardID = cs.CardID 
WHERE (YEAR(NOW())-YEAR(cs.tanggallahir))<20 
AND nominalbelanja <> 0 
GROUP BY DAY(gp.date) 
UNION 
SELECT '20-35' AS Usia ,COALESCE(COUNT(*),0) AS jmlCust, `date` FROM getpoint gp 
LEFT JOIN customer cs ON gp.CardID = cs.CardID 
WHERE (YEAR(NOW())-YEAR(cs.tanggallahir)) BETWEEN 20 AND 35 
AND nominalbelanja <> 0 
GROUP BY DAY(gp.date) 
UNION 
SELECT '36-50' AS Usia ,COALESCE(COUNT(*),0) AS jmlCust, `date` FROM     getpoint gp 
LEFT JOIN customer cs ON gp.CardID = cs.CardID 
WHERE (YEAR(NOW())-YEAR(cs.tanggallahir)) BETWEEN 36 AND 50 
AND nominalbelanja <> 0 
GROUP BY DAY(gp.date) 
UNION 
SELECT 'TOTAL' AS Usia ,COALESCE(COUNT(*),0) AS jmlCust,`date` FROM getpoint gp 
LEFT JOIN customer cs ON gp.CardID = cs.CardID 
WHERE nominalbelanja <> 0 
GROUP BY DAY(gp.date) 
ORDER BY `date` 
) t right join test1 on (test1.Usia = t.Usia);
```